# Reversing an array by recursively splitting the array in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, reverse, function-definition, divide-and-conquer

```
string recursion(int arr[], int arrSize) {

if(arrSize == 1){
    return to_string(arr[0]);
}
string letterLeft, letterRight, letterFull;

//logic1: Normal Recursion
//letterFull = to_string(a[n-1]) + " " + recursion(a, n-1);

//logic2: D&C ------------------------------------------------------ <
letterLeft += recursion(arr, arrSize/2);
letterRight += recursion(arr + arrSize/2, arrSize-arrSize/2) + " ";
letterFull += letterRight + letterLeft;

return letterFull;
}
```

I recently used the 'logic2: D&C' for splitting an array recursively to reverse them (more like Divide and Conquer).

(i.e. if 2,5,4,1 is given as input, output should be 1,4,5,2).

It passed all test case like the example I just gave. Yet, I felt like I don't really understand the flow of recursion. I am here to get help from someone in explaining what happens in the 'logic2: D&C' step-by-step with an example flowchart & values if possible?

PS:

> I took help from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40853237/18762063 to implement this 'logic2: D&C'.
> Edits - Made little changes to argument list.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::string` and `std::reverse`?

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes, I am allowed to use `std::string`, but not `std::reverse`. Thanks.

Comment: Does it have to be recursive? An iterative reverse loop is simpler and more efficient. Pretty close to the programming equivalent of 2*2 = 4.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, that could have been simpler, but I was limited to use recursive method (with D&C) though it isn't efficient as reverse loop. Thanks.

Comment: What is `+ " "` doing there?

Comment: Can your algorithm reverse an empty string?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I used them to space out each output thrown from recursion. And I didn't check with empty string.

Comment: Always check with an empty string. When I'm testing code, my or anyone elses, the first things I feed it are nothing and the lyrics of the Major General's song from the Pirates of Penzance. Shakes out a lot of early bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear why there are used objects of the type `std::string`. To reverse an array of objects of the type `char` there is no need to use the class `sdt::string`. This is just inefficient. The function can look the following way

```
void recursion( char arr[], size_t arrSize )
{
    if ( not ( arrSize < 2 ) )
    {
        std::swap( arr[0], arr[arrSize-1] );
        recursion( arr + 1, arrSize - 2 );
    }
}
```

Comment: oops!, My bad, I used vectors for 'logic1: Normal recursion' and used string to return the final result. Missed to change it for the 'logic2: D&C' where I use char[ ] instead. Thanks.
However, I would like to ask if there is an approach using Divide & Conquer, rather than swap? Thanks.

Comment: @AravindShanmugam I think for the reverse algorithm using the approach will be inefficient.

Comment: Thank you for you answer and I understood that D&C approach is inefficient in this case of reverse algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The point of divide and conquer algorithms is breaking your data down to smaller and smaller pieces while processing it.

If you want to reverse an array for example, than the following should happen:

1. The data is split into 2 equal parts and the order of these parts gets switched (so the back half becomes the front half, and the front half becomes the back half)
2. The 2 split parts are then also broken down to 2-2 equal parts, and get reversed.
3. And so on, until the splits are 1 length, so they can't be split any further, resulting in a fully reversed array.

[Reading material on D and C algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm#:%7E:text=A%20divide%2Dand%2Dconquer%20algorithm,solution%20to%20the%20original%20problem.)

Comment: Thank you for the material, and I did understand the flow of D&C after some observation.